# Parse syntax error when accessing CMS->Pages inside admin

Tags: admin, error, cms, fatal-error, admin-controller

I am getting the following PHP fatal error and blank white screen when trying to access the `CMS >Pages` page inside admin:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in
>   Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php on line 139

Has anybody come across this issue before or know the best way to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is a core Hack**

Some one directly edited core file of Magento `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php`. As the error indicates, go to the line 139 in that file and you can find PHP error (most probably some syntax error) there.

I recommend you to replace that file with original file. DO NOT EDIT THE CORE FILE DIRECTLY. [**Here is the link**](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php) for original file. May be you can make a comparison and find out the problem.

Find it and shoot down. Good luck.

---

<sup>**Side Note :** the file may be in local codepool too. app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php`. If such file exists, then make changes there.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Rajeev, turns out the core file had in fact been edited by a previous developer.

Answer (score 2):

I think your core code is corrupted.
[Here is how line 139 should look like](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php#L139)

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('cms_page_prepare_save', array('page' => $model, 'request' => $this->getRequest()));
```

There is no `%` in it.
Get the clean version of the file from a new magento instance and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Marius, a previous developer had changed the core file which caused the issue as you explained.